# Spatial query in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I’m trying to run the example code below in Neo4j Desktop but keep getting the error - **Unknown function 'point.withinBBox'**

```
WITH point({x: 0, y: 0, crs: 'cartesian'}) AS lowerLeft, point({x: 10, y: 10, crs: 'cartesian'}) AS upperRight
RETURN point.withinBBox(point({x: 5, y: 5, crs: 'cartesian'}), lowerLeft, upperRight) AS result
```

Is the function not available in the Desktop version?

Comment: Upgrade required

Answer (score 0):

What version of Neo4j are you using? The [`point.withinBBox` function](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/spatial/#functions-withinBBox) was added in Neo4j v4.4 ([see changelog](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-4.4-changelog#440)) so if you're using an older version you'll want to upgrade to a more recent version of Neo4j to use this function.